# Gradle error Android studio 1 import facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook, facebook-share

Following error while importing facebook sdk on android studio 1,

http://i60.tinypic.com/160exl4.png

, Also ,  Do user needs fb app on android mobile to use fb share option in my app , or any other option is available

I want to share a custom story or link on facebook wall of user about my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can share to Facebook or do any share tutorials, you need:

Your environment set up
A Facebook app properly configured and linked to your Android app, with Facebook Login enabled
The Facebook SDK added to your project

There good documentation is available for sharing option on fb by your android app.[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share)